# How to upgrade Blobfuse to the latest version

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

We are using blobfuse version 1.0.2 and would like to upgrade it to latest version like 1.3.1. How we can upgrade it to latest version without uninstalling and reinstalling blobfuse ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you may raise the issue in github [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-fuse/issues/467).

And the answer is that:

now 1.3.2 is the latest. At this time you can clone the source could and build it, command git clone https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-fuse. It will create an azure-storage-fuse directory, if you run ./build.sh from this dir it will create a blobfuse binary in the build directory. you can mount just like an installed version Eg: ./build/blofuse ~/blobfusemntdir --tmp-path=< your path>